# Ununderstandable alternate form of a function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, radicals, math-software

Helo, i've a doubt about this function: $$f(x)=\frac{\sqrt{16 - x^2} - x\sqrt{46 + 25( \sqrt[4]2})}{x\sqrt{(46 + 25 (\sqrt[4]2)}}$$

 I want to find the roots of $f(x)$ for $f(x)=0$,
Wolfram alpha has given me this results:
Alternate form assuming $x$ is positive: $$x=\sqrt{\frac{16}{47+25\sqrt[4]2}}$$
I don't have idea where tath came from, can you explain me please?

Comment: where is the function?

Comment: semantics, I will edit the post, wait

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because for positive $x$ we obtain:
$$\sqrt{16-x^2}=x\sqrt{46+25\sqrt[4]2}$$ or
$$16-x^2=x^2(46+25\sqrt[4]2)$$ or
$$x^2=\frac{16}{47+25\sqrt[4]2}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i'm still working on my math skills so i don't understand very well your answer. I'm agree with you when you say $\sqrt{16-x^2}=x\sqrt{46+25\sqrt[4]2}$, but i don't understand well the other 2 equation. Can you help me to understand them better?

Comment: @Fabio: The first step simply squares each side of the equation (which are both known to be nonnegative due to the assumption that $x>0$).

Comment: Yeah, that was an easy step must be the late hour here, thank you very much I fully understand it now :)